# What is causing a SIGSEGV on _updateNumSections in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash

We get the following every once in a while.  We cannot recreate this error.

Does anyone know what specifically causes this?  It seems like the UITableView is in some odd state.  I have ran Instruments to look for over-releasing memory, etc. but am not seeing much.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
    libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3068f06b _objc_terminate + 103
    libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x30502e3d __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 53
    libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x30502e91 std::terminate() + 17
    libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x30502f61 __cxa_throw + 85
    libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3068dc8b objc_exception_throw + 71
    CoreFoundation                      0x335141bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 103
    CoreFoundation                      0x33513649 ___forwarding___ + 509
    CoreFoundation                      0x3348a180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    UIKit                               0x31bb2ff3 -[UITableViewRowData(UITableViewRowDataPrivate) _updateNumSections] + 67
    UIKit                               0x31bb2f53 -[UITableViewRowData invalidateAllSections] + 51
    UIKit                               0x31bb2d09 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateRowData] + 65
    UIKit                               0x31bafab7 -[UITableView _rectChangedWithNewSize:oldSize:] + 111
    UIKit                               0x31bae833 -[UITableView setFrame:] + 159
    UIKit                               0x31bb5e0f -[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 275
    UIKit                               0x31b820bd -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 121
    UIKit                               0x31b674e9 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 337
    UIKit                               0x31bb5e0f -[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 275
    UIKit                               0x31b820bd -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 121
    UIKit                               0x31b674e9 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 337
    UIKit                               0x31bae9fd -[UIScrollView setFrame:] + 421
    UIKit                               0x31bb5e0f -[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 275
    UIKit                               0x31b820bd -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 121
    UIKit                               0x31b674e9 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 337
    UIKit                               0x31bb5e0f -[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 275
    UIKit                               0x31b820bd -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 121
    UIKit                               0x31b674e9 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 337
    UIKit                               0x31bb9193 -[UIViewControllerWrapperView setFrame:] + 63
    UIKit                               0x31bb5e0f -[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 275
    UIKit                               0x31b820bd -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 121
    UIKit                               0x31b674e9 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 337
    UIKit                               0x31bb5e0f -[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 275
    UIKit                               0x31b820bd -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 121
    UIKit                               0x31b674e9 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 337
    UIKit                               0x31b9922f -[UILayoutContainerView setFrame:] + 55
    UIKit                               0x31bb90a9 +[UIViewControllerWrapperView wrapperViewForView:frame:] + 225
    UIKit                               0x31bd6201 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 105
    UIKit                               0x31bd618d -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 33
    UIKit                               0x31bd5a33 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 187
    UIKit                               0x31c5aceb -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 15
    UIKit                               0x31c5abe7 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 227
    CoreFoundation                      0x33480571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 25
    UIKit                               0x31b7eec9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 85
    UIKit                               0x31b7ee69 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 33
    UIKit                               0x31c5aa8b -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 271
    CoreFoundation                      0x33480571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 25
    UIKit                               0x31b7eec9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 85
    UIKit                               0x31b7ee69 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 33
    UIKit                               0x31b7ee3b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 39
    UIKit                               0x31b7eb8d -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 357
    UIKit                               0x31bb8bd9 -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 17
    UIKit                               0x31c5a815 -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 81
    CoreFoundation                      0x33480571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 25
    UIKit                               0x31b7eec9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 85
    UIKit                               0x31b7ee69 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 33
    UIKit                               0x31b7ee3b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 39
    UIKit                               0x31b7eb8d -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 357
    UIKit                               0x31b7f423 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 343
    UIKit                               0x31b7dbf5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 369
    UIKit                               0x31b7d56f -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 263
    UIKit                               0x31b66313 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 299
    UIKit                               0x31b65c53 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5091
    GraphicsServices                    0x311a5e77 PurpleEventCallback + 667
    CoreFoundation                      0x334e7a97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 27
    CoreFoundation                      0x334e983f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 167
    CoreFoundation                      0x334ea60d __CFRunLoopRun + 521
    CoreFoundation                      0x3347aec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 231
    CoreFoundation                      0x3347adcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 59
    GraphicsServices                    0x311a541f GSEventRunModal + 115
    GraphicsServices                    0x311a54cb GSEventRun + 63
    UIKit                               0x31b90d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 405
    UIKit                               0x31b8e807 UIApplicationMain + 671
    MyApp                              0x0009a188 main (main.m:5)
```

Comment: Post your tableView code from the view that crashes.

Comment: Not sure which one it might be.  Can't tell from the stack even which table view they might be looking at.  Do you have an idea what might be wrong?  This is driving me nuts. :)

Comment: Also, this is not consistently crashing.  I suspect it's some nasty over release on memory but not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by looking in your console log. There will be a message indicating which class has been sent `updateNumSections`.

Make sure you aren't making calls to this table view on a background thread. That can cause these kinds of crazy crashes.

Make sure your table view datasource isn't deallocating before the table view.

A suspicion here would be an over-release (as you suggest), so run Static Analysis just to find the bone-headed stuff. Also make sure you're using accessors rather than using ivars directly (the #1 cause of over-releases).

Comment: Thanks for all these great suggestions.  I "think" the problem I was having was I was calling popViewControllerAnimated in viewDidDisappear in the view with the UITableView.  I was trying to pop the view when they switched tabs or any other action.  It was resulting in two pops of the view controller which resulted in this crash.  I removed the popToViewController from viewDidDisappear and put it in the actual delegate for the tab bar controller.  What still doesn't make sense is I could not recreate the issue.  Either way, I still believe this would result in some funky behavior too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and like you suggested in your comment on Rob Napier's answer, it should be implemented in the tabBarController instead of on viewDidDisappear.

Running Zombies in instruments will show you that a call to updateNumSections gets made to a deallocated object.

For anyone looking up this issue, here is the code you should use in your tabViewController, given a navigationViewController that gets called within a tab that is no longer shown.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    //Always go to the root controller when accessing a tab.
    //If any navigation controller that must remember its last state, change this for viewController == or !=
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //Do not use code on disappear, instead popToRoot on tab selection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure I don't update table view on background thread.

Thanks @Pierre-Francoys, I add a Zombies Option and it tell me the selector `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` sent to deallocated object. So I clear the dataSource and delegate of tableView in my viewController. And it works very well.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    _tableView.dataSource = nil; 
    _tableView.delegate = nil;
}
```